# Flutter Provider: notifyListeners() to specific target

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

**Background info:**

For my flutter project, I am using `listview.builder` and `provider`:

`ListView.Builder`:  getting the `buttons` info using provider and `listen` is `false`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final buttons = Provider.of<mybuttons>(context, listen: false);

return Container(    
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: buttons.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return singleButton(listIndex: index);
    },
  ),
 );
}
```

**Then...** where, `singleButton()`: This will run according to the `length` from the parent widget.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final singleButtonInfo = Provider.of<mybuttons>(context).buttonIndex[listIndex];

return FlatButton(
  child: Text(singleButtonInfo.text),
  onTap: (){
       changeText(listIndex);
  }
 );
}
```

Thus, if the `length` is 5, then there will be 5 flatbuttons with index from 0 to 4.

Using the `onTap`function, I want to change the text of that specific button (ie. if 3rd button is clicked, then I want to change only the 3rd button without rebuilding all buttons).

```
changeText(int listIndex){
  ...logic
  notifyListeners();
}
```

**Here is question:**

My understanding of `notifyListeners()` is that it will notify everything with the `Provider.of<T>(context)`and those widgets will be rebuilt (ie. all 5 buttons will be rebuilt with the new data).

Because each button will have an unique index, is there a way to target a specific button to be rebuilt and ignore the rest?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, found this: https://pub.dev/packages/property_change_notifier Might be userful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, note that the optimization that you're trying to do is, most of the time, pointless.

Optimizing rebuilds has usually very little benefits, and may not be worth the added complexity and is useful only when the states change at a very frequent rate (like animations).

That said, what you're looking for is [Selector](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html).

[Selector](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html) is a custom may of consuming providers which, as opposed to [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html)/[Provider.of](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider/of.html), has a way to filter undesired updates.

For example, if a widget only needs `MyModel.text`, then instead of:

```dart
final model = Provider.of<MyModel>(context);

return Text(model.text);
```

we can use [Selector](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Selector-class.html) like so:

```dart
return Selector<MyModel, String>(
  selector: (_, model) => model.text,
  builder: (_, text, __) {
    return Text(text);
  }
);
```

Such code will call `builder` again *only* when `MyModel.text` changes, and ignores changes to anything else.

Comment: Well, that was exactly what I was looking for. I know what you mean about the optimization but wanted to tackle this problem to understand Flutter/provider better! Thanks for the help Remi! =)

Comment: Is there a way to use Selector to filter for changes on a single property, but still have access to the reset of the model data inside the builder?

Answer (score -3):

You can see the code above

```
...
return FlatButton(
  child: Text(Provider.of<mybuttons>(context).getText(buttons)),
  onTap: (){
   Provider.of<mybuttons>(context).changeIndex(buttonIndex);
  }
);
```

And `mybuttons` notifier must have a data structure that store the states of buttons and must have `getText` and `changeIndex` methods.

I am just wondering why don't you just simple a stateful widget?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However your solution simply moves the `Provider.of` variable into multiple location, making it even more convoluted. The solution is unrelated to the question.