# In Flutter, should a provider wrap the datamodel, or should it implement each member of the model as a variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, data-class

I wrote an app last year where I needed to update a model across multiple screens, so I used provider with changeNotifier. I implemented the provider like so;

```
class SurveyProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin{
  String name = "";
  String postCode= "";
  
  void addSurvey(Survey survey){
    this.name = survey.name;
    this.postCode = survey.postCode;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

The provider is for the data model below. To keep things simple, I've reduced it to just two variables.

```
class Survey{
  final String name;
  final String postCode;
}
```

I implemented each variable of the model as a variable inside the provider. Should I have implemented the entire model inside the provider like this?

```
class SurveyProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin{
  Survey survey;
  
  void addSurvey(Survey survey){
    this.survey = survey;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

I'm not sure which way is the correct way to do this, but I have a feeling the way I've done it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a universally correct approach to state management, but I would say that what you did was not wrong.

The first approach is better when you have a 1 to 1 link between the object and the provider.

However, the second option is more solid if you need a provider for complex and different entities, since it allows you to separate the objects logic from their provider's.

The best solution depends on the size and complexity of your project.

Comment: For the second option, If I had a page that just listened "name" inside the Survey Model, would changes to "postCode" cause that page to update, even though the page does not use "PostCode"

Comment: If you are using a Consumer to listen to state changes then yes, it would. You can use a selector to listen only for specific attributes (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59080044/18162964)